# How do I write a loop that skips certain iterations?

Tags: javascript, loops

This is the exercise:

> Create a function "MyFunction" with 1 parameter, that will print
>   integers between 1 and its parameter, using a particular algorithm:
>
> MyFunction(25) 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25
>
> MyFunction(29) 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27

It appears that it will print the numbers between 1 and the parameter, but for every 3 iterations, it will skip 3 numbers.

How do I write a simple function that does this using JavaScript?

Thank you.

Edit: I have seen the exact same exercise posted in the Python forum, but I don't really know much Python. I have already tried doing a simple loop, but I need help with the specific part of the algorithm where you are supposed to skip the 3 numbers.

[How do I amend this function so that it prints integers between 1 and its parameter, using a particular algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744631/how-do-i-amend-this-function-so-that-it-prints-integers-between-1-and-its-parame)

Edit 2:

```
function MyFunction(num) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i += 1);
    console.log(i);
}

console.log(MyFunction(25));
```

That's the only thing I've tried which just logs 26 to the console.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping multiple elements in a FOR loop, Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092638/skipping-multiple-elements-in-a-for-loop-javascript)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Please see my edit

Comment: @DavidSampson it's not

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i <= num; i += 1);
    console.log(i);` is not correct syntax for a `for` loop, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). Note the lack of semi-colon at the end of the `for` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction(num) {
    let i = 0;
    let str = "";

    while(i < num) {
        i++;
        str = str + i + ",";
        if(i % 3 === 0) {
            i = 3 + i;
        }
    }
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    console.log(str);
}

myFunction( 29 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely forgot about using the while arguement. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's ok. It happens. Enjoy coding.